# Where can I find the Netbook of Feats for D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew

I remember a web page called the *Netbook of Feats* that had a huge list of feats for 3.5e. Does anyone know where that went?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest edition of the **Netbook of Feats** that I can find is Version 12.4, published in May 2007. [The official site](http://www.datadeco.com/nbofeats/) is down, but you can download the HTML version here:

https://www.adnddownloads.com/en/resource/the-netbook-of-feats-version-124

Take care when using the Netbook of Feats, as not all of these feats are balanced to the same standards as the official material. I once had a character take the feat Bonded Weapon from this netbook, which grants +2 to attack and +1 to damage with one individual weapon, at the cost of -2 when using other weapons. As a high-level fighter specialized in one weapon, Lord Aramil never wielded anything but [his own named weapon](http://www.d20source.com/2005/12/thundaril-minor-artifact-weapon), and so this feat was very powerful.

Comment: A lot of the feats are actually quite weak compared to official feats published later in 3.5.  I had a curated list where I tried to straighten up some of the mechanically more cumbersome feats and throw away the less useful ones.

Answer (score 3):

[D&D Wiki has the last published version of the Netbook of Feats](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/The_Netbook_of_Feats_Version_12.4_of_the_Netbook_of_Feats).

We'd always made some effort to balance the feats but it's a tricky business in 3.5 with so many options and ways to combine things. I think any time you venture outside the core rules for a game you want to be a little self limiting so you keep the game fun for the style of play you are doing.